# Query regarding Appointment Urgent!

Tags: uk, vfs-global

Can the appointment for a UK visitor visa get cancelled if someone by mistake starts the process all over again?

What I mean is that I got the appointment confirmation email, but I went back to that page of the UK Visa website where it redirects you to the VFS website to schedule an appointment. On that page it says any prior appointments would be cancelled. So does this mean my appointment is cancelled?

I tried scheduling my appointment again but it gives internal error...

Comment: I would say just from reading this question that the wording sounds like they meant any additionally booked appointments would cause the original to be cancelled, just visiting the page itself wouldn't cause this.

Comment: Normally if i was re-visting the VFS website, i was able to see my booked appointment..But after I revisITed the UK website,  I do not see the appointment details. It keeps saying internal server error.

Comment: We are not VFS experts. I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be directed to the VFS tech support team